# Include Financial Type in Payment Processor Transaction Information

Tags: civicontribute, contributions, payment-processor, financial-types

The PayflowPro payment processor extension for CiviCRM attempts to include the financial type by including the following item in the data that is sent to the PayflowPro API. Although, I had to modify this a bit so that the financial type is still sent to PayflowPro when a user signs up for an event.

```
$payflow_query_array = [
...
      'COMMENT1' => urlencode($params['contributionType_accounting_code']),
...
    ];
```

Do the other payment processor extensions for Civi do this - send the financial type to the payment processor dashboard? Specifically, the big ones: Stripe, Authorize.NET, and IATS?

Answer (score 2):

Not all payment processor sends financial type or other details related to accounting to the Payment gateway from Civi. But each payment processor allows altering the params that are sent to the payment gateway via `hook_civicrm_alterPaymentProcessorParams` hook.